# Update multiple rows using CASE WHEN - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table `ACCOUNT` of structure as follow:

```
ACCOUNT_ID  | ACCOUNT_STATUS| 
004460721   |      2        | 
042056291   |      5        | 
601272065   |      3        |
```

I need to update the three rows at once using one `SELECT` statement such that, the second column will be 5, 3, 2 respectively.
I used the following query but seems there is something missing

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT
SET ACCOUNT_STATUS = CASE   
WHEN ACCOUNT_STATUS = '004460721' THEN 5  
WHEN ACCOUNT_STATUS = '042056291' THEN 3  
WHEN ACCOUNT_STATUS = '601272065' THEN 2  
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID IN ('004460721','042056291','601272065')
```

My question, is this way correct? if no, can I use `CASE WHEN` statement and how or I only have choice of using `SUB-SELECT` to acheive that in one statement?
Kindly, notice this is for `SQL ORACLE`

Comment: What kind of update are you trying to do? Set them all to the same value?

Comment: @SarathiKamaraj it is updated now, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @MultiThreader it is updated now, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @hawk did you tried schurik answer below. I think that might work...

Comment: Go to this link- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm, read it thoroughly, make sure you understand every bit of it and then either edit or close this question.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson it is updated now, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @SarathiKamaraj Yes, something is wrong, you can check the link I posted in the comment below.

Comment: @Rachcha I read it thoroughly and I found nothing about CASE WHEN, some posts here uses it in ORACLE which confuse me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170864/update-with-case-and-in-oracle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok based on the fiddle you have given i have tried these and it worked for me

```
create table account(  account_id number primary key,
                           account_status varchar2(30));

insert into account values(1, '5');
insert into account values(2, '3');
insert into account values(3, '2');

select * from account


update account
set account_status= case
when account_id=1 then '2'
when account_id=2 then '5'
when account_id=3 then '3'
END

select * from account
```

I didn't use the where condition

Comment: @hawk yeah it is not working in fiddle.. I tried in my oracle apex   apex.oracle.com       it worked fine for me

Comment: Correct, I found the problem with Fiddle, I should run `select` with `update`, if I run them separately Fiddle will rollback. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

try the following

```
update account
set account_status = CASE account_id 
                     WHEN 004460721 then 2 
                     WHEN 042056291 THEN 5 
                     WHEN 601272065 THEN 3 
                     END
WHERE account_id IN (004460721, 042056291, 601272065 )
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Though bit late I would like to add one point to the above answers. The Where condition is **important** because with out that, the query will update all rows.

Answer (score 1):

how about changing

```
WHEN ACCOUNT_STATUS = '004460721'
```

to

```
WHEN ACCOUNT_ID = '004460721'
```

etc. in the original code