# oracle SQL increase fields value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hello I have got a simple Question in SQL oracle. Which is I need to increase employee'a salary by *7% if its under IT department*, 
*12% under business department*, 
 AND *5% for other departments*
lastly display 
revised salary **with two decimal places** 
heres my employees table as follow:

```
employeeID      Dept       Salary
emp1             IT         2000
emp2             BS         3000  
emp3             MK         4000
emp4             EG         5000
```

NOTE: BS = business dept, MK = markiting dept, EG = engineering dept

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760632/update-multiple-rows-using-case-when-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581240/3989608)** expression in your **UPDATE** statement. It is verbose and easy to interpret than **DECODE**.

For example,

**To display:**

```
SELECT employeeID,
       Dept,
       Salary,
       CASE
          WHEN dept = 'IT' THEN
             salary + (7/100) * salary
          WHEN dept = 'BS' THEN
             salary + (12/100) * salary
          ELSE 
             salary + (5/100) * salary    
       END as "New_Salary"
FROM employees;
```

**To update:**

```
UPDATE employees
SET salary=  CASE
                WHEN dept = 'IT' THEN
                   salary + (7/100) * salary
                WHEN dept = 'BS' THEN
                   salary + (12/100) * salary
                ELSE 
                   salary + (5/100) * salary    
              END;
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to update, i want to display the new changes along with current values like: empid,dept,old salary,revised salary.

Comment: @OTAMD Ok, see the updated answer. Please mark it as answered, would help others too.

Answer (score 1):

Use decode function:

```
UPDATE employee
      SET salary = salary*decode (dept,
         'IT', 1.07,
         'BS', 1.12,
         ...,
         1.05)
```