# how to update sql table based on various criterias

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I have 3 different postcodes areas that 3 salesman cover,
**For example:** Salesman 1 covers postcode areas: AL, AD, DS, etc...  Salesman 2 covers postcode areas: CD, DD, KK, etc... Salesman 3 covers postcode areas LL, PL, MM, etc...

I want to update `Quotes` table column `quSalesman` where postcodes from the `companies` table matches one of the three areas mentioned **above**.

I am currently doing this

```
$allcoPostcodes = $db1->query("SELECT coPostcode FROM companies WHERE coPostcode = '$coPostcode'");

$coPostcodoPurp = $db1->getval("SELECT coPostcode FROM companies WHERE ( coPostcode LIKE 'AL%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'BN%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'CT%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'CM%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'CO%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'CB%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'CB%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'DA%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'GY%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'HP%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'IP%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'JE%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'LU%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'ME%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'MK%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'NR%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'NN%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'PO%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'PE%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'RH%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'RM%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'SG%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'SL%' OR coPostcode LIKE 'SS%' OR
                                                                        coPostcode LIKE 'TN%')", "coPostcode");


if ($allcoPostcodes == $coPostcodeRed) {
    $db1->query("UPDATE quotes SET quSalesman = '90' WHERE quId > '133366' AND quCoId = coId AND coPostcode = $coPostcodeRed");
} else if ($allcoPostcodes == $coPostcodeOran) {
    $db1->query("UPDATE quotes SET quSalesman = '91' WHERE quId > '133366' AND quCoId = coId AND coPostcode = $coPostcodeOran");
} else if ($allcoPostcodes == $coPostcodoPurp) {
    $db1->query("UPDATE quotes SET quSalesman = '77' WHERE quId > '133366' AND quCoId = coId AND coPostcode = $coPostcodoPurp");
} else {
    $db1->query("UPDATE quotes SET quSalesman = '16' WHERE quId > '133366' AND quCoId = coId");
}
```

**Note** areas `coPostcodeRed` and `coPostcodeOran` are litterally the same just the poscode area changes as seen in `coPostcodoPurp`

The above currently works meaning that it updates the data in the table however it only runs the else statment and dosen't properly check the if or else if statements or at leasts that is what is seems to me as all the values in `quSalesman` equal are set to 16 and if I remove the else statment they set to 77 which is the last else if and I am not sure why this is happening, obviously I check the postcodes and some of the should be set to 90 and some to 91 and etc...

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170864/update-with-case-and-in-oracle) doesn't solve your problem.

Anyway, if you print your $coPostcodeRed and the others before the condition is checked, you can understand if it is reading the same as you think it is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).